# Javafx Webview video fullscreen

Tags: javafx, webview, desktop-application, html5-fullscreen

I'm writing a web browser with Javafx. I've come a long way in the project. However, I noticed that the web view doesn't have full screen support. I did a lot of research on this, but I didn't get any results. I don't have a chance to change the background and the language. What can I do about it? Thank you for your answers.